# GDB in Cygwin is missing sigfe.s?

Tags: gdb, cygwin

After doing some programming assignments for school, I decided to start working on some side projects I had in mind. I decided to install vim on Windows and link it properly using Cygwin. I installed gcc and gdb at first, to try to see if everything worked. I made a quick C file that had a few printf's so I could step into them using gdb.

I can set a breakpoint in main, run the program, get the first printf, but the moment I try to step into the next line, an error appears.

```
(gdb) step
_sigfe_puts () at sigfe.s:7019
7019    sigfe.s: No such file or directory.
```

I thought I didn't install gdb properly, so I reinstalled to no luck. I tried using UltraGDB to see if it would help, but the same thing happened, this time giving me a much clearer error.

```
Can't find a source file at "C:/cygwin64/cygwin/src/cygwin/cygwin-2.8.0/cygwin-2.8.0-1.x86_64/build/x86_64-pc-cygwin/winsup/cygwin/sigfe.s" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

I had a suspicion it had to do with permissions, so I tried to look up said directory and turns out it really does not exist. C:/cygwin64/ does not have a cygwin folder, much less a subfolder called src and so on. What I did find is that there is a folder called x86_64-pc-cygwin in the cygwin64/usr but it does not have a winsup folder at all.

I'm lost as to what I can do now to fix this error, it's been annoying me for the past few days and have not found any fixes regarding this. I assume GDB is looking for this file in the wrong place, but if I have gdb installed using the Cygwin setup executable then shouldn't this be working anyway? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

**Complete test run w/error:**

```
$ gdb ./test
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 7.10.1-1) 7.10.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-cygwin".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./test...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1004010ed: file test.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/User/test
[New Thread 13236.0x4c0]
[New Thread 13236.0x824]
[New Thread 13236.0x3078]
[New Thread 13236.0x374]

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:6
6         printf("Hello\n");
(gdb) step
_sigfe_puts () at sigfe.s:7019
7019    sigfe.s: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
7020    in sigfe.s
(gdb)
7023    in sigfe.s
(gdb)
_sigfe () at sigfe.s:19
19      in sigfe.s
(gdb)
20      in sigfe.s
(gdb)
21      in sigfe.s
.
.
.
(stops responding after various steps)
```

Comment: `sigfe.s` is part of the source code for Cygwin's C runtime library and as such it wouldn't normally be present on your computer. You should either use the `next` command to step over the function call to `printf`, since its not very useful to step through library code line by line. If you really do want to step through the library code then you'll either need to download its source code or use `stepi` which will step the code assembly instruction by assembly instruction. For more details on these commands see: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html

Comment: Sorry, but next wouldn't be useful if I start calling some functions I write. 

For example, making a function foo() be called after the first printf, if next is used it wouldn't provide the information I would need, such as the individual lines in the foo() method. I would need to know what is happening inside that function, so I do need step, not for library code stepping but rather my own code.

Comment: So use `step` to step into the functions you wrote and have the source code for, and use `next` to step over the library functions you didn't write and don't have the source code for.

Comment: While now I am able to step into the function that I want to, it  does not go line by line. I have

int a;
int b;

printf("Foo");

and stepping into the function only gives me printf("Foo") rather than int a. 

Would it work if I install the gdb source code in windows and try to set up an alias in my bashrc?

Comment: The lines `int a;` and `int b;` don't actually result in any code being generated in the executable so you can't step through them.

Comment: So it's giving me an error because I'm trying to step into the actual printf function itself, which is an assembly file and I don't even have it. I understand now, I guess I had a misconception about it. It will take a while to get used to it, since the server my college used made it possible to keep stepping into each line of code without stepping into the library code itself.

Makes sense now, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`sigfe.s` is a source file dynamically created during cygwin build.

It is present in the build tree:

```
$ find . -iname "*sigfe*"
./x86_64-unknown-cygwin/winsup/cygwin/sigfe.o
./x86_64-unknown-cygwin/winsup/cygwin/sigfe.s
```

and it seems the only file with such characteristics

```
$ find . -iname "*.s"
./x86_64-unknown-cygwin/winsup/cygwin/sigfe.s
```

In theory it should be included in the `cygwin-debuginfo` package

```
$ cygcheck -l cygwin-debuginfo | grep -i "s$"
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.8.1-0.1/newlib/libc/machine/x86_64/memcpy.S
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.8.1-0.1/newlib/libc/machine/x86_64/memset.S
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.8.1-0.1/newlib/libc/machine/x86_64/setjmp.S
```

You can highlight the issue on the cygwin mailing list.
https://cygwin.com/cygwin/lists.html